# MySQL JOIN Queries to find references and conversions

Tags: mysql

I have the following three tables User, References and Conversions. The goal is to find out which users have given how many references and how many of these references have been converted.

```
user
id  user_id
1   001
2   002
3   003
4   004
5   005
6   006
7   007
8   008
9   009
10  010

references
id  referer_id  referee_id
1   001     005
2   001     006
3   002     007
4   003     008
5   004     009
6   005     010

conversions
id  user_id
1   005
2   006
3   007
4   008
5   009

REPORT
id  references(count)   conversions(count)
001 2           2
002 1           1
003 1           1
004 1           1
005 1           0
```

Please suggest a MYSQL Query to produce the above Report.

Copied from the comment into original question

```
SELECT 
      user_id, 
      referenceCount, 
      conversionCount 
   FROM 
      users u 
         JOIN (SELECT referer_id, 
                      COUNT(referee_id) AS referenceCount 
                  FROM references 
                  GROUP BY referer_id) r 
            ON r.referer_id = user_id 
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS conversionCount 
                       FROM conversions) c 
            ON c.user_id = r.referee_id GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: what have you tired?

Comment: SELECT user_id, referenceCount, conversionCount FROM users u 
JOIN (SELECT referer_id, COUNT(referee_id) AS referenceCount FROM references GROUP BY referer_id) r 
ON r.referer_id = user_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS conversionCount FROM conversions) c 
ON c.user_id = r.referee_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my result using the following SQL command. Many thanks to @DRapp for the help.

```
SELECT 
      u.user_id, 
      count( r.referer_id ) as CntRefs, 
      count( c.user_id ) as CntConvert
   FROM 
      users u 
         JOIN reference r
            on u.user_id = r.referer_id
            LEFT JOIN conversions c
               on r.referee_id = c.user_id
   group by
      u.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with joins, but they should be left-joins.

```
SELECT 
      u.user_id, 
      count( distinct r.referer_id ) as CntRefs, 
      count( distinct c.user_id ) as CntConvert
   FROM 
      users u 
         LEFT JOIN references r
            on u.user_id = r.referer_id
            LEFT JOIN conversions c
               on r.referee_id = c.user_id
   group by
      u.user_id
```